# Android remove Shadow from Tab in TabLayout

Tags: java, android

I got a custom TabLayout with custom Tabs. The TabLayout is higher then the Tabs.

[image]

Is there a way to remove the shadow above the tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `app:elevation="0dp"` in your TabLayout and It'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit  in styles.xml to fix the issue.